# Retrieving text within span class with XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am using python to retrieve various metrics from a website (e.g., likes, twitter shares, etc.) While XPath retrieves text just fine, I'm having trouble with these metrics (text within span).

```
<span class="pluginCountTextDisconnected">78</span>
```

Now I need to get that "78", but Python does not return anything when I feed it the XPath.

Here's the XPath, just in case:

```
//*[@id="u_0_2"]/span[2]
```

Python code:

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2  
from unicsv import CsvUnicodeReader

req=urllib2.Request("http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/3866370/reddingsbrigade-redt-369-mensen-zomer-.html")
tree = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
fb_likes = tree.xpath('//*[@id="u_0_2"]/span[2]')
print fb_likes
```

Comment: Show your python code first.

Comment: Agree with alecxe. Since your XPath worked fine but your python didn't, you really need to show your Python code

Comment: Added the Python code.

Comment: First, the code you posted is invalid (double-quotes in a double-quoted string). Second, the xpath matches nothing (i.e. `fb_likes` in an empty list).

Comment: The quotes within quotes was my mistake when I posted it here, but it was correct when I ran it.
The fact that 'fb_likes' is an empty list is actually my problem, because I would assume it would contain the number of likes (78 in this case)

Comment: `fb_likes` is empty because the xpath expression does not match anything (i.e. HTML element). In fact, when I ran it, `//*[@id="u_0_2"]` didn't match anything. So you might want to review the target HTML once more to find the actual pattern, then you can worry about the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `/text()` to the xpath:

```
//*[@id="u_0_2"]/span[2]/text()
```

Comment: The rest of your xpath might not be accurate.  Try //*[contains(@class, "pluginCountTextDisconnected")]/text()

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your span is in the `iframe`, so you need be 'inside' the iframe, to get the text (btw, `//span[@class='pluginCountTextDisconnected']/text()` is correct way, but you are outside the iframe). So you need to read the `src` like:

```
a = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/3866370/reddingsbrigade-redt-369-mensen-zomer-.htm").read())
iframe = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(a.iframe["src"]).read())
fb_likes = iframe .xpath("//span[@class='pluginCountTextDisconnected']/text()")
```

sorry, didn't test the code, it's just a general idea.

**Update**

```
import urllib2, lxml.html

iframe_asfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=recommend&app_id=&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df112fd0c7b19666%26domain%3Dwww.nu.nl%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.nu.nl%252Ff62d30922cee5%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nu.nl%2Fbinnenland%2F3866370%2Freddingsbrigade-redt-369-mensen-zomer-.html&layout=box_count&locale=nl_NL&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=true&width=75')
iframe_data = iframe_asfile.read()
iframe_asfile.close()

iframe_html = lxml.html.document_fromstring(iframe_data)

fb_likes = iframe_html.xpath(".//span[@class='pluginCountTextDisconnected']/text()")
print fb_likes[0]
```

prints `78`

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives me a ton of error messages. 
I'm really unfamiliar with html, and getting pretty desperate. Is there maybe another way to get the text from iframe with python other than XPath?

Comment: @Zlo another way is to take src attribute value of the iframe as url and open in urllib2, please see my update

Comment: @ German Thanks. I know I'm becoming annoying, but the first method you described would suit me much better (since I need to do the same thing for hundreds of articles, and it wouldn't be convenient to fish out the src attribute in every article). However, when I run the code
`iframe = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(a.iframe["src"]).read())`
I get the 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'iframe' error.

Comment: The thing is that as I can see now, these iframe are generated dinamycally, so you can see them via browser dev tool, but if to look at page source, you won't find them( there is script, that creates iframes within widgetsection. That is why you can't find iframe at the moment of "read()" action. Can't help here, sorry, can suggest only what I suggested above with Update, sorry :(